# Ошибка при поиске input формы bs4

Tags: python, input, bs4

def apply_promo(promo_code):

```
form_url = "https://store.standoff2.com/ru/profile/185030612/coupons-activate"
response = requests.get(form_url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
form = soup.find("form")
form_data = {}
for input_tag in form.find_all("input"):
    name = input_tag.get("name")
    value = input_tag.get("value")
    if name:
        form_data[name] = value


form_data["promo_code"] = promo_code


submit_url = form_url  
response = requests.post(submit_url, data=form_data)


print(response.text)
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что скрипт не находит форму input, html-код которой выглядит так:
`<input aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите промокод" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="">`

**Ошибка:** `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\AutoPromokodsGoldStandoff.py", line 94, in <module> extract_promocodes(str(message_texts)) File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\AutoPromokodsGoldStandoff.py", line 34, in extract_promocodes apply_promo(promo_code) File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\AutoPromokodsGoldStandoff.py", line 46, in apply_promo for input_tag in form.find_all("input"): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Я 100 раз перепроверил, input действительно существует...

Comment: При попытке открыть указанный в программе URL выдаётся окно "УКАЖИТЕ СВОЙ АККАУНТ" в котором нет никакого тега <form>.  Там есть теги <script>, которые (по всей вероятности) и организуют процесс логина.